# SSIS connection attribute DTS:Retain="True" renders connection manager broken

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-connection

What function does the DTS:Retain value perform when it is included in the XML of a connection manager (.conmgr) file in SSIS? 
Testing the connection works with this attribute, but when selecting a table for destination (OLEDB) an error is returned (0xC0202040)

(DTS:Retain="True"):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:ConnectionManager xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:ObjectName="My connection"
  DTS:DTSID="{1e8fac80-da08-43b1-a7a0-25ae2a866631}"
  DTS:CreationName="OLEDB">
  <DTS:PropertyExpression
    DTS:Name="ConnectionString">@[$Project::MyConnection]</DTS:PropertyExpression>
  <DTS:ObjectData>
    <DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:Retain="True"
      DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" />
  </DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

Comment: Please post your error message

Comment: When it is set to true it keeps the same session open when running the package. It is useful when you need to set up transactions via execute sql tasks or components. Otherwise I would say that there is no need to use this setting.